Identify why zfs is busy, cannot be destroyed
I have a zpool (SSDs) comprised of three drives.  This pool was moved to a UBUNTU system from a retired FREENAS system, and there is no "valuable" or meaningful data on the drives.  The list of filesystems in this pool is:
SSDs                        102G  1.66T   102M  /SSDs
SSDs/hs-b44gx               102G  1.75T  7.30G  -

I would like to delete the SSDs/hs-b44gz FS but destroy is not allowed because it is apparently busy.
I do not remember creating this zfs, and have no idea what "type" it is.  (I tried "set mountpoint=" so I could see its data, but got
cannot set property for 'SSDs/hs-b44gx': 'mountpoint' does not apply to datasets of this type

My search for help with this found articles like this one (https://www.truenas.com/community/threads/unable-to-delete-datasets-busy.108347/).  In general, the solutions I've found involve either deleting snapshots or unmounting the ZFS.  But in this case, there are no snapshots apparently, and as mentioneed, mount (unless I misunderstand) is not valid.
What can be done to "unbusy" this ZFS?  I am fairly new to administration of ZFS - I fought it for years with FreeNAS... now I would like to work with it on Ubuntu.  Clearly I could just wipe it out and create an lvol or somesuch.  But zfs sounds like a better answer.
